Correcting heading levels for accessibility
I've been struggling with choosing the right headings for certain elements since I mostly use React and want to focus on reusable code.
Since I always organize my code with the following hierarchy:

route (h2)
section inside route (h3)
article inside section (h4)
hero section (h1)

I thought this approach would be appropriate. Otherwise, I wouldn’t know how to distinguish between them while respecting their order.
Here is my example
    <div className='page'>
      <div className='page__wrapper'>
        <main>
          <section className='home-route'>
            <div class='home-route__wrapper'>
              <h2 className='sr-only'>Home route</h2>
              <div className='home-route__content'>
                <section className='hero sr-only'>
                  <h1 className='hero__title'>Pick your courses/articles for learning</h1>
                </section>
                <section className='cards-section'>
                  <div className='cards-section__wrapper'>
                    <h3 className='sr-only'>Cards</h3>
                    <div className='cards-section__content'>
                      {
                        cards.map((card, index) => (
                          <Card key={index} item={card}></Card>
                        ))
                      }
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

How I structure website:

div [page] (wrap whole content - '/' route)
div [layout] (for some route + e.g. navigation - '/users')
section [route] (home, contact, user ... e.g. /users/userId)
section (some section inside that route)
article (some article inside that section)


What do you meant by route? What purpose does having an h2 called "home route" serve to users? Can you provide more context to what the content is? It's hard to recommend semantics without detailed content

Also, it's invalid HTML to have an h1 followed by an h3.

Since I mostly use SPA (Single-page application), I have structure like this:

div [page] (meaning whole page that wrap everything)
layout (something that is common for multiple routes or e.g. route + navigation)
section [route] (home, users, contact ...)
section [classic section] (inside that route)
article (inside that section)
se


End-users don't care about any of that, so your heading structure shouldn't be derived from that. Each page is its own document, and should be treated as such

Sorry, I don't understand. Since I use SPA, how do I need to organize it? How then to handle routes? p.s. I'm not doing it for users only but to myself and other developers as well.

Can you share example content for one of your pages?

The underlying technology, SPA or otherwise, shouldn't have any influence on how you use headings

I can give a link to one of my projects on the GitHub LINK

For instance, based on the image of /players/men/new/, that page should have only one heading: an H1 that reads something like "Add new player".

But as I know page can have only one H1 (I have that on the home route), so that's why I put H2 for each route

I'm confused as to why you think the parent directories/routes need to be represented as headings. For instance, this page shouldn't have a "questions" heading just because that's part of the URL

I think it's necessary to inform both developers and users (using screen readers technologies) to know on which route they are currently. In the same, I though it was right for better organization of the code. Also, I use  for route container, so it's one more reason for me to use headings. Is it wrong to use  for route wrapper?

That's not what headings are for. Headings are for giving the document an outline. If you want to inform users about their current location from a route/path standpoint, use breadcrumbs.

And yes, it's also wrong to use sections for that purpose

Headings are for giving the current document an outline, not for informing users of their current location within a website's directory structure (or a SPA's routes).
If you want to provide users context of where they are within the structure of your website or SPA, use breadcrumbs instead.
Using a modified example from the repo you linked to in the comments, here's the markup of what an "add new player" page should look like:
<header>
  <nav aria-label="Main">[...]</nav>
</header>
<nav aria-label="Breadcrumbs">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/players">players</a></li>
    <li><a href="/players/new" aria-current="page">add new player</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
<main>
  <h1>Add new player</h1>
  <form>[...]</form>
</main>

"Home" and "Players" should not be headings on the "Add New Player" page. There's not a "Home" section of content on this page, or a "Players" section of content on this page, so they shouldn't be headings.

Ok, thank you, but does it mean that I should use  and  for each route? As far as I know, only one  is allowed and one  as well.

Each URL is a separate page/document, which should have one  and one . You're not rendering multiple routes at the same time on the same page, so I'm confused as to why you think you'd have multiple routes on one page.

Why wouldn't it have multiple routes on one page? I need a route for "contact", "projects", "home" and similar and it's SPA. There is one main and one h1 and the content of the route changes dynamically depending on which route you are currently.

Right, but the URL is changing so essentially it's a different page at that point, and should have a different H1—even if there's not an actual page reload happening

Inspect the markup of this example as you click around it. Each route is treated as a separate document, and each has its own H1: https://react-spa-example.netlify.app/

You should only be rendering one route at a time, and each should be its own self-contained document.

Agree, thank you for clarification!
